# c++ mystic transfer of class array

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, parameters, transfer

```
class Array
{
    double *mx; int mn;
public:

 Array();
~Array(){delete []mx};
 Array& operator-(Array& b);  //first right way
 Array operator -(Array b);  //wrong way, but I don't understand why
};

Array::Array ()
{ 
  mn=10;
  mx=new double[mn];
}

//first, works perfectly
Array& Array::operator -(Array& b)
{
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<mn ;i++)
       this->mx[i]-=b.mx[i];

  return *this;
 }


// here is Error

Array Array::operator -(Array b)
{ 
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<mn ;i++)
       this->mx[i]-=b.mx[i];

  }


int main() {
   Array x,b;
   x=x-b;
}
```

If I use the first overload , all works right.

But if I use the second, all is compiled well, but when program is executed, i receive many errors like this:

```
"c++ ** glibc detected *** double free or corruption"
```

[image: http://s41.radikal.ru/i091/1105/e1/2349397c04a2.png]

I can't figure out why this occurs.

As I understand, when I call `Array Array::operator-(Array b)`, the object must be copied and all must be well, but there is error.

well i've read that i've to object that are allocated at the same place in the memory. but i've tried to do this:

```
        Array Array::operator +(Array b)
 { Array c;
 int i=0;
 for(i=0;i<mn;i++) 
this->mx[i]+=b.mx[i];
 cout<<&this->mx<<" "<<&b.mx<<endl; 
exit(0);
 return c; }
```

i 've expected to receive same addresses in memory....

answer is 0xbfb45188 0xbfb45178 why are they equal?

furhermore, when i declare here    name of class(A object)
  compiler must give a new memory in stack for object
   where am i wrong? i dont understand....

Comment: And your question is? source and question should be separate - take a look at some other C++ questions here before posting stuff like this.

Comment: think about copy construction , pass by const ref ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `operator-` *should* take a reference, otherwise you're performing needless copies. However, it doesn't *need* to. It certainly should return a value, because a `-` semantically gives you a new object. When you write `c = a-b`, you don't expect `a` or `b` to change.
- As noted above, you don't *need* to take a reference into `operator-`, and in your second example you take by value. This is OK, except you have a second bug:
- - Your `Array` class has an internal buffer that it `new`s on construction, and `delete`s when it gets destroyed (`~Array`).
- - However, it does *not* have a user-defined copy constructor, and the buffer is not automatically copied for you; only the pointer `mx` is copied.
- - So, when you copy the `Array`, you now have *two* objects with a pointer `mx` pointing to the same buffer. When one copy goes out of scope, that buffer is `delete`d; some time later, the other copy tries to do the same, and `delete`ing the same buffer twice is an error.

My suggestions:

- Write a copy constructor and `operator=` into your class `Array`. Very important.
- Have `operator-` take a reference anyway. It makes mores sense.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
Array Array::operator -(Array b)
```

This line will create a copy of your array. As you don't have a copy constructor the compiler will just make a copy of all the fields including the pointer field "mx".  Now you have two objects both pointing to the same allocated memory. When each one is destructed the delete [] will be called....

You need to either write a copy constructor or ensure that no copying takes place.
To do that pass by reference

```
Array Array::operator -(Array& b)
```

(That should probably be const too... but that's a different issue)

Comment: note that the return value here should also probably be a reference, ie
`Array& Array::operator- (Array& b)`, to avoid copying on the way out

Comment: @bodes: Wrong. `operator-` should return a new object.

Comment: @Tomalak specifically regarding @JohnB's last code snippet, regarding ensuring that no copying takes place... depending on the level of compiler optimization, returning by value may make copies, no?

Comment: @bodes: Sure. And what's wrong with that? When you write `a = b - c`, did you want `b` or `c` to be modified? No. You want `a` to be a brand new object. (And if you create one inside `operator-` then return it by reference, you're returning a dangling reference.)

Answer (score 3):

You violated the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).